# Data displays on HTML after clicking anywhere on the page

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic4

I am fetching data from Firestore, added the required code inside `ngOnInit()`. Problem is when I do `ionic serve`, my `home.html` remains blank, but I  can see data in `console.log`.

Data comes only after I click somewhere on the page. Why is it happening?

Here is my `home.ts`

```
 ...
export class ViewdailyreportPage implements OnInit {

  constructor(private firestore: AngularFirestore) { }

  dailyreports:any = [];
  ngOnInit() {

//where condition with timestamp
let start = new Date('2020-03-29');
let end = new Date('2018-01-01');
firebase.firestore().collection("dailyreport").where("timestamp", ">=", start)
    .onSnapshot(querySnapshot => {
        var cities = [];
        querySnapshot.forEach( doc=> {
  const timeinmillsecs = doc.data().timestamp.seconds * 1000; //1. get timestamp and make it in milli
  let a1 = new Date(timeinmillsecs); // 3. convert to simple date
  let show_year_month_date =  a1.getFullYear()+'/'+(a1.getMonth()+1) +'/'+a1.getDate(); // 3.convert to imple date
         const data = doc.data();
         data.timestamp = show_year_month_date;
         this.dailyreports.push(data);
         console.log(this.dailyreports);
        });
    });
  }
}
```

`home.html`

```
<ion-content>
  <!--<div class="info col-11"  [innerHtml]="list.dr_describe | safe: 'html'">{{list.q_describe}}</div>-->

  <div  class="info col-11" *ngFor="let list of this.dailyreports">

    <div id="chtv">
      Click here to view what {{list.name}} did.
    </div>

    <br/>
    <span [innerHtml]="list.desc | safe: 'html'">{{list.desc}}</span>
  </div>
</ion-content>
```

Screenshot on `ionic serve` and after I click:

[image]

### Edit 1

I have imported `ChangeDetectorRef` and called it where data loads but still same problem, first time it loads and if I refresh it doesn't till I click somewhere. Here is my `home.ts` code:

```
export class ViewdailyreportPage implements OnInit {

  lunch = "dal"; daily_report_desc='';
  dinner = "rajma";
  constructor(private firestore: AngularFirestore,public modalController: ModalController,private cd: ChangeDetectorRef) 
  {
      //where condition with timestamp
let start = new Date('2020-03-29');
let end = new Date('2018-01-01');
firebase.firestore().collection("dailyreport").where("timestamp", ">=", start)
    .onSnapshot(querySnapshot => {
        var cities = [];
        querySnapshot.forEach( doc=> {
  const timeinmillsecs = doc.data().timestamp.seconds * 1000; //1. get timestamp and make it in milli
  let a1 = new Date(timeinmillsecs); // 3. convert to simple date
  let show_year_month_date =  a1.getFullYear()+'/'+(a1.getMonth()+1) +'/'+a1.getDate(); // 3.convert to imple date
         const data = doc.data();
         data.timestamp = show_year_month_date;
         this.dailyreports.push(data);
         console.log(this.dailyreports);
         this.cd.detectChanges();
        });
```

Comment: Look try to put the whole content inside the constructor in settimeout like 250ms and see if they are viewed

Comment: Have you tried detecting changes through ChangeDetectorRef?

Comment: Your questions are getting more succinct, user2828442 - thank you. Images should not contain text annotations though - readers with screen-readers can't see them, and search engines won't scan the content. However you can add alt-text in the "add description here" placeholder.

Comment: @MostafaHarb did not work with this

Comment: @MuhammadUmair can you post a reply, i am not friendly with this

Comment: Reminder: the personal pronoun is a capital letter "I", with no exceptions. If you're struggling to remember this, install an English spellchecker into your browser, and ensure you use it before publishing.

Answer (score 0):

This happened with me in 2 previous projects, in the first it was styling problem so the viewport was not recognized by the view on page load and will need click after page load so it gets forced to autfit so in this project I recreated my css with good styling and it got to work.

And in another project was because a conflict in plugin, in browsing was normal but in mobipe was the problem since the keyboard plugin had a bug at that version so I installed a keyboard of specific version. In your project there are some warnings they could be plugin issues, and could be styling issues.

But since data are being get normally then it's view problem for now, so try to comment your html view and add any thing in it like an ionlabel with text hi and see if it appears, since the toolbar is appearing so you have conflict in design in ion content.

If so try to remove styling and see if Firestore data are being viewed, if they are viewed then the problem in css else the problem is conflict in Firebase plugin itself (maybe it needs upgrade or downgrade version to a stable one) see and tell what happens with you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
import { ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';

constructor( private cd: ChangeDetectorRef ) {}
```

And when you finally have your data. try calling

```
this.cd.detectChanges();
```

Comment: Did as you guided but still same problem,i have edited my question, you can see my code